# Tabula-py windows- UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position N: invalid start byte

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to read `pdf` file like

```
di = read_pdf('test.pdf', output_format= 'json', encoding='utf-8', guess = False)
```

Its working fine on linux. But on windows getting error `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8'` codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position N: invalid start byte", Please help me to know the issue.

Comment: Apparently, UTF-8 isn't the right choice. Did you use the same document on Linux and on Windows? What does the documentation say about the `guess` parameter, is this about encoding perhaps?

Comment: Yes. Guess parameter is for the portion of the page to analyze per page. Default is True. But you are right, I just changed **encoding = 'cp1252'** and Its working perfectly for me. Thanks lenz.